# Firestore: Inequality filter property and first sort order must be the same. Failing where condition and order in different fields. Is this Expected?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of documents like this:

```
{
   uid: <UNIQUE_USER_ID>,
   lastLoggedIn: <TIMESTAMP_IN_NUMBER>,
   ...
}
```

when I try to fetch the data using:

```
Server.db
    .collection(firebasePaths.funfuse_verified_users)
    .where('uid', 'not-in', notToIncludeAccounts)
    .orderBy('lastLoggedIn', 'desc')
    .startAt(startAt)
    .limit(limit)
```

I get an error saying:

```
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: inequality filter property and first sort order must be the same: uid 
and lastLoggedIn
```

Is this a known limitation of firebase or am I doing something wrong ? I want to query all the users which aren't in an array `using not-in` and then sort those results based on `lastLoggedIn` timestamp activity.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As the error message says, in order to be able to use `not-in` you must first order on the same field:

```
Server.db
    .collection(firebasePaths.funfuse_verified_users)
    .orderBy('uid')
    .where('uid', 'not-in', notToIncludeAccounts)
    .orderBy('lastLoggedIn', 'desc')
    .startAt(startAt)
    .limit(limit)
```

This also means that the results will be order first on `uid` and only then (so if there are multiple results with the same `uid` value) on `lastLoggedIn`. If you need them in another order, you will have to resort them in your application code.

Comment: wow, just found out you can have multiply orderBy  thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

This might not work or be so clean with collections, but since I cared about the sorting order and did not want to have the filtered field determine the sort, I just ended up adding an additional boolean field to my object and then queried on that boolean field instead.

So if I had

```
 @Data
  public class Foo{
    private String url;
    ....
  }
```

and I was trying to get the results where the url is NOT null, but the query wasn't working, I then added a field called `urlPresent` to my object and used that field in the where clause instead.

```
  firestore
            .collection("foo")
            .whereEqualTo("field1", field1)
            .whereEqualTo("urlPresent", true)
            .orderBy("field2", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
            .orderBy("field3", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
```